# Why are the results of array_walk() function so crazy?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Why the following code returns second character of the array values?

```
$name = array("John","Frank","Peter");
function myFunction($name) {
echo $name[1];
}
array_walk($name,"myFunction"); //output ore
```

Comment: http://php.net/array_walk

Comment: What did you expect? And why? Also why do you blame `array_walk`?

Comment: Why do you think it does that?  What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_walk()` passes each value of the `$name` array to your callback `myFunction()`. (The variable `$name` you have inside your callback is *not* the same variable `$name` that you are passing to `array_walk()`. The `$name` array is (assumed in this case) global in scope whereas the $name` in your callback is only in scope inside that function). You are then explicitly echoing out the second character of that variables string value.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose.

```
// First iteration
John
 ^

// Second iteration
Frank
 ^

// Third iteration
Peter
 ^
```

Comment: You might want to explain about the scope of the variable `$name`. It might cause confusion.

Comment: Thank you John for your comprehensive explanation